# In Java 7 ConcurrentHashMap, why segment lock is required while writing? Why can't we use Unsafe again to keep things non-blocking?

Tags: multithreading, java-7, nonblocking, concurrenthashmap, compare-and-swap

While going through the internal implementation of Java 7 ConcurrentHashMap, I noticed that to set the new Segment, we are using the Unsafe class which does Ordered write and make use of Compare and Swap algorithm thus supporting non-blocking behaviour.

**My doubt is why Concurrent HashMap don't use compare & swap algorithm or something similar to keep the read & write to Singly linked list non-blocking instead of acquiring lock on segment and then writing to singly linked list?**

Answer (score 0):

The methods in the Unsafe class are generally unsafe to use.  They are only used when the software engineer writing the libraries has figured out that they can be used because of other constraints, such as knowledge of what might simultaneously be accessing the data, or knowledge about how primitives are implemented on various processor architectures.

In this case, some engineer at Oracle has determined that the Unsafe class can be used for the Segment manipulation, but not for the singly linked list.

Comment: Yes, I understand that Unsafe class should not be preferred instead we could have used AtomicReferenceArray to accomplish the same. Nevertheless, what I am trying to understand what is the limitation that resulted in using lock on the segment.

Comment: What you should be trying to understand is what the unusual situation is that permitted the use of the Unsafe class where it was used.

Comment: Actually, that is already mentioned in documentation of ConcurrentHashMap that it's used to reduce the levels of indirection as AtomicReferenceArray internally uses Unsafe to provide the ordered write instead of volatile  writes. Also, it's helpful in avoiding volatile write which creates the memory barrier if my understanding is correct thus causing slighty better performance. Please correct me if I am wrong.